# Vim Java code completion?

Tags: java, vim

Is there something equivalent to OmniCppComplete for java in vim ?
I know of eclim but I think it is overkill for such a simple feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1785

Answer (score 4):

Also found VJDE - http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1213 - Need to evaluate which one is better/more up-to-date

Comment: Judging from the amount of downloads, the last updates to the code, and the rating, your script seems to the better choice. FYI, I haven't used either.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have some options for code-completion above.

I would recommend also grabbing a copy of [TagList](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273), which provides a sidebar displaying the structure of your current file.

The ctags which TagList uses can also be used for fast navigation in Vim.  Ctrl+] over the text "curiousMethod()" should take you to the definition of that method.